# Laravel 4 permissions not showing

Tags: laravel

Im getting blank page while using Laravel, I already gave perms to the folder with

```
find app/storage -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

But still blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try...

run php artisan serve from your projects root dir, and see if the browser comes up if you go to `http://localhost:8000`

And give us feedback in the run... because now we only can guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you're at on solving this problem. But, you'll want your permissions to be at 775 not 777. Also, you may want to check ownership on your htdocs folder and all files within that directory. This is pure speculation since I don't know what kind of dev enviroment you're using, but i run a lamp stack and when ever I have to create a new enviroment the htdocs folder is always owned by root. You may want/need to chown that to your user account.

Answer (score -1):

How about chmod -R 777 app/storage

If that does not work it is a htaccess problem propably

Last but not least, and it might sound stupid, but can you verify if the directories are all there in app/storage ? Because it happened to me that i was checking out from svn and empty directories are not transferred, so make sure you check that app/storage/logs exists.

If there is no log file written then it sure has to do with access levels, for example not being able to write into those dirs, hence the chmod command above. And i posted that because i had never seen anybody do it the way you did.

At least if you are able to write to the log file you can find out what exactly is wrong.
But we have so minimal information it is hard to help you in a good way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: How do you know ??? Are you a moderator troll ? As long as he does not try and answer if it helped or not, how for god's sake do you know if this does not provde an answer ? Feels like you just wanted to say something just to say something. Your comment does not help either that is for sure. Get a life man, you have to many time on your hands. As if i give a thing about reputation, just want to help the guy. But seems that is not appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  FYI, those comments are auto generated by the mod process.  Someone flagged your post, and mods (more than 1) review the post.  If you want the user to try stuff to see if it fixes it, that's what comments are for.  I could also have downvoted the the answer, but I could see that you were trying to be helpful, and didn't have enough rep to comment yet.